# Same C# MVC application diffrent css style / links / logo's,

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc app. wich is needed for several brands of the company.
all functionality is the same. exept layout, title's logo's links,.. exect.

My first tought was just copying the app and change the the style.

My second tought was to create extra libraries where all css, logo, links,.. are coming from for each diffrent brand.

but i think none of both are good solution's.

I can not realy find much information on google about it. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong keywords...

Does anybody has experience with this problem en what is the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use scss. 
1) Change the extension on the css file(s) to scss. 
2) add @import "companyTheme.scss"; at the top of the file
3) change all the company relates values to an scss variable  $company-logo or mixin
4) create a companyTheme scss file for each company
5) compile the scss file so then your css files will have the same name

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.Net MVC, you have `section` and `layout` which you can use to make your styles and layout specific to certain views, roles, areas, etc. For example in your `.cshtml` file:

```
@{
     Layout = Viewbag.Company.Equals("X") ? "Some Layout" : "Another";
}
```

Or

```
@section Styles {
    your css here
 }
```

Followed by rendering the styles or scripts in the layout

```
 @RenderSection("Styles", false) // or true if it is always needed
```

Or you can check for it first

```
 @if(IsSectionDefined("Form") {
      <div class="row">
           @RenderSection("Form")
      </div>
 }
```

You can do this using Dependency Injection in order to make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, **different companies** should have **different set of resources**

You should not mess up those resources, to avoid human error, for sure.

With `mvc` there are lot of ways to handle it:
- store the directory in database and keep the url dynamically.
- using key atrributes and control by Atrribute in Controller
- using javascript libraries to handle it in front end
...
Each way has it own pros and cons, so you can try to explore to find out which one suites your situation.

Happy coding